# mean in relation to the five number summary

Tags: statistics, means

Can the mean of a set of data be equal the Q1 value of the five number summary? hence can 75% of the data be above the mean? can you please provide an example of this?

Comment: Try the numbers: $0,1,1,1,1,1,2$. Here $Q_1 = Q_3 = 1$, and the mean is 1. It's true that 75% of the data is not strictly above the mean but it is greater than or equal to the mean and the mean is equal to $Q_1$. I'm sure you can construct a data set that has the property you're looking for.

Comment: Indeed: Take the $n$ numbers $\{0,0,0,\ldots,0,n\}$, which has mean $1$, and all except one of the numbers are below the mean. This example can, of course, be smoothed out if you want it to, but the idea is quartiles and means, while expressing the same basic idea, do not say anything conclusive about eachother.

Answer (score 1):

$\{0,10,11,12,12,13,13,13\}$ has $Q1=\text{mean}=10.5$

Indeed 75% of the data (the 6 biggest values) are above the mean.

Comment: Not challenging your answer (+1), but conventions for defining the quartiles vary widely among textbooks and software. In R `x = c(0,10,11,12,12,13,13,13); fivenum(x)` returns `0.0 10.5 12.0 13.0 13.0`; `mean(x)` returns `10.5`; and `summary(x)` returns
   `Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.` = 
   `0.00   10.75   12.00   10.50   13.00   13.00`, respectively. Function 'fivenum' uses Tukey's _fourths._ (Decent formatting impossible in Comment.)